# jQuery Form Processing With PHP to MYSQL Database Using $.ajax Request

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, forms

**Question:** How can I process a form using jQuery and the $.ajax request so that the data is passed to a script which writes it to a database?

**Problem:**
I have a simple email signup form that when processed, adds the email along with the current date to a table in a MySQL database. Processing the form without jQuery works as intended, adding the email and date. With jQuery, the form submits successfully and returns the success message. However, no data is added to the database.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

```
    <!-- PROCESS.PHP -->
    <?php
        // DB info
        $dbhost = '#';
        $dbuser = '#'; 
        $dbpass = '#';
        $dbname = '#';

        // Open connection to db
        $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die ('Error connecting to mysql');
        mysql_select_db($dbname);

        // Form variables
        $email      = $_POST['email'];
        $submitted  = $_POST['submitted'];

        // Clean up
        function cleanData($str) {
            $str = trim($str);
            $str = strip_tags($str);
            $str = strtolower($str);
            return $str;
        }
        $email  = cleanData($email);

        $error = "";
        if(isset($submitted)) {
            if($email == '') {
                $error .= '<p class="error">Please enter your email address.</p>' . "\n";
            } else if (!eregi("^[A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9._%-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$", $email)) {
                $error .= '<p class="error">Please enter a valid email address.</p>' . "\n";
            }
            if(!$error){
                echo '<p id="signup-success-nojs">You have successfully subscribed!</p>';

                // Add to database
                $add_email  = "INSERT INTO subscribers (email,date) VALUES ('$email',CURDATE())";
                mysql_query($add_email) or die(mysql_error());

            }else{
                echo $error;
            }
        }
    ?>

<!-- SAMPLE.PHP -->
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Sample</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){ 
                // Email Signup
                $("form#newsletter").submit(function() {    
                    var dataStr = $("#newsletter").serialize();
                    alert(dataStr);
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "process.php",
                            data: dataStr,
                            success: function(del){
                                $('form#newsletter').hide();
                                $('#signup-success').fadeIn();
                            }
                    });
                return false;
                });             
        }); 
</script>
<style type="text/css">
#email {
    margin-right:2px;
    padding:5px;
    width:145px;
    border-top:1px solid #ccc;
    border-left:1px solid #ccc;
    border-right:1px solid #eee;
    border-bottom:1px solid #eee;
    font-size:14px;
    color:#9e9e9e;
    }   
#signup-success {
    margin-bottom:20px;
    padding-bottom:10px;
    background:url(../img/css/divider-dots.gif) repeat-x 0 100%;
    display:none;
    }
#signup-success p, #signup-success-nojs {
    padding:5px;
    background:#fff;
    border:1px solid #dedede;
    text-align:center;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#3d7da5;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<?php include('process.php'); ?>
<form id="newsletter" class="divider" name="newsletter" method="post" action="">
    <fieldset>
    <input id="email" type="text" name="email" />
    <input id="submit-button" type="image" src="<?php echo $base_url; ?>/assets/img/css/signup.gif" alt=" SIGNUP " />
    <input id="submitted" type="hidden" name="submitted" value="true" />
    </fieldset>
</form>
<div id="signup-success"><p>You have successfully subscribed!</p></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead if using data: dataStr, use:

```
data : {param: value, param2: value2}
```

This is the proper way to do it for POST requests.

Also, I recommend using a form plug-in, like [this](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/).

Comment: His method is the most common usage actually

Comment: Plus one to the form plugin, makes life much easier. I often have forms that post back to the same page. I send an extra parameter (ajax=true) which i use to alter what the page returns to the browser ie. just a page fragment that I can inject via innerHTML.

Comment: His method is the most common way of doing it, actually. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Plus one to the form plugin, makes life much easier. I often have forms that post back to the same page. I send an extra parameter (ajax=true) which i use to alter what the page returns to the browser ie. just a page fragment that I can inject via innerHTML.

Answer (score 0):

check the response coming from the process.php file.echo and die the post values and alert the response because everything seams to be written correctly just matter of sending the post values to process.php.
the syntax of Serialize could also be

```
jQuery('#newsletter').formSerialize();
```